# deleteObject undefined error

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to execute delete code

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'deleteObject' of undefined or null reference

Here is my code...Not sure what is going wrong here.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = context.get_web();
     var oList;
    var listitems;
   function deletelistItems() {
      var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('TracingList');
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Recepient' /><Value Type='Text'>Recepient Created!</Value></Contains></Where>");

listitems = oList.getItems(query);
context.load(web);
context.load(listitems);
context.executeQueryAsync(function deleteListItems(){
    var listCount = listitems.get_count();
    for(var i =listCount; i>=0; i--){
        var itemToDel = listitems.itemAt(i);
        itemToDel.deleteObject();
    }    }, function deleteQF(sender, args) {
alert("Request Failed. \nError: " + args.get_message());});}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the iteration on `listCount-1` because the array is zero-based.

Also, after the loop has finished you need to do a new `executeQueryAsync` to actually save / send the changes to the server.

So complete example:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = context.get_web();
     var oList;
    var listitems;
   function deletelistItems() {
      var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('TracingList');
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Recepient' /><Value Type='Text'>Recepient Created!</Value></Contains></Where>");

listitems = oList.getItems(query);
context.load(web);
context.load(listitems);
context.executeQueryAsync(function (){
    var listCount = listitems.get_count();
    for(var i =listCount -1; i>=0; i--){
        var itemToDel = listitems.itemAt(i);
        itemToDel.deleteObject();
    }

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){ 
        alert("Success"); 
    }, function(sender, args) {
        alert("Request Failed. \nError: " + args.get_message());
    });   
}, function (sender, args) {
alert("Request Failed. \nError: " + args.get_message());});}
```

Comment: i want to see the value that's passing in list count. how do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question? You just need to change the part above in your for-loop declaration

Comment: Noworries, i had the alert pop up with itemcount value. i changed the code to for(var i=listCount-1; i>=0;i--).... But the issue is, items are not deleted in first button click..i had to click it 3 times to get the items deleted.

Comment: And i still see this error when i hit F12.

Comment: After the for-loop has finished you will need to do a new `executeQueryAsync` call to actually send the request to SharePoint to delete the items